# Control Options Javascript Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

How can I position zoomControl options and panControl positioning next to each other but in the middle? I used LEFT_CENTER command but it does not insert them next to each other.
Thanks in regards..

```
map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.300299, 34.471664),
        zoom: 6,
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        mapTypeControl: true,
        //mapTypeControlOptions: { style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU, position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP },
        mapTypeControlOptions: { style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU, position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP },
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
        panControl: true,
        panControlOptions: { position: google.maps.ControlPosition. LEFT_CENTER},
        zoomControl: true,
        zoomControlOptions: { style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.BIG, position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP },
        scaleControl: true,
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the default controls, you have to use the [Control Positioning](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#ControlPositioning) , so you can not place them next to each other in the LEFT_CENTER.

But if you use Custom Control so you can change position of custom control, you can see [this example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/control-custom). In that example, you can change the position of the custom control by change its margin value. ex: `controlUI.style.marginBottom = 100px;` (You can see the change in this link: http://jsfiddle.net/cmw3zy9p/)

But for default controls, you have to follow the supported control positions.

Comment: how can i change it for zoomControl or mapTypeControl, thanks in regards.@ztan

Comment: both `zoomControl` and `mapTypeControl` are default controls, so you have to use the default positioning, you can not change the margin of them.